# initial row index of filtered datatable

Tags: javascript, filter, datatable, row

From a datatable with filters applied, I need to identify the row indexes of the table which are filtered.

```
var table = $('#MY_TABLE').find('table').DataTable()
console.log(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).indexes());
```

provides new generated indexes of the filtered data (`_DT_RowIndex`) but I need original indexes (`rowIndex`) which can be displayed in the explorer with

```
console.log(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes());
```

How to efficiently extract this information?
The purpose is to apply the same filters to another tables.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, maybe not the best one, I added a sequential ID column at the front of the table.

```
var filtered_rows = $('#MY_TABLE').find('table').DataTable().rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).column(0).data();
```